# How to remove parent element of a list group item

Tags: javascript

I have a list and in each list group item there is a delete button. I would like the delete button to remove the list item. At the moment i can only delete the button but i would like the whole li element to be removed

```js
function remove(ev) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(ev.target.id);
  elem.this.parentNode.id.remove();
  console.log(elem.this.parentNode.id);
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="remove(event)" class="Button">Click</button>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="remove(event)" class="Button">Click</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `parentNode.remove()`

```
function remove(ev) {
  var elem = ev.target; // get the delete button element
  elem.parentNode.remove(); // remove the parent li element
}
```